# Is it possible to launch RDP files with Virtual Machine Connection instead of Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I like the auto-scaling (while maintaining the correct aspect ration) of the VM that Virtual Machine Connection has over Remote Desktop Connection application when you're not in full-screen mode.

Is there any way to force all *.rdp files to open with the Virtual Machine Connection application instead?

Comment: Instead of asking about your proposed solution, it is better to ask how to achieve your desired end goal, namely, how to get the auto-scaling feature for all your RDP connections (then mentioning an idea you had is fine, so long as you don't *limit* answers to just that one approach).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Virtual Machine Connection, but assuming that it can handle the .RDP filetype, it would simply be a matter of changing the file association for that extension.

Within the Windows 10 Settings app, open Apps > Default Apps > "Choose defualt apps by file type". Then change the .rdp extension to open with the Virtual Machine Connection executable.

[image]

On Windows 7/2008, this setting is found in Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Set Associations

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The standard Remote Desktop Connection app is capable of doing what you ask. The feature is known as **Smart Sizing**. To enable it on Windows 8.1 or higher:

1. Start the Remote Desktop connection in widowed mode (or press CTRL+ALT+BREAK to toggle between full screen to windowed mode.)
2. In the top left corner menu choose **Smart Sizing**

If you have a version of Windows prior to 8.1, you can enable this feature as follows:

1. Open the saved .RDP file for your connection in Notepad, or to affect all new connections, edit the hidden `default.rdp` file in your Documents folder
2. Add the following line to the file:

   ```
   smart sizing:i:1
   ```